# How can we find out if some number is of the form f(x) in pari?

Tags: pari

I use pari very much for my mathematical research. But I couldn't figure out how to find out if a number can be represented as f(x) for some number x and function f. For example, Euler's totient function φ(x) is defined as the number of natural numbers less than x that are relatively prime to x. Now I wanted to figure out that, given a number n, is it representable as φ(x)-1 for some positive integer n? I can't test it for *all* the positive integers, so how can I do it?

Comment: Your question is more about math than pari-gp. You want the Euler totient function inverse. You can find relevant info [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/265397/inversion-of-the-euler-totient-function).

Comment: There is no way to test if a number can be represented by an arbitrary function f. (its a computationally impossible problem because it would require computing an infinity of values). For a particular function such as phi, that is a mathematical question (it depends heavily on the properties of the function).

Comment: http://www.numbertheory.org/php/carmichael.html

Answer (score 0):

For you specific example with Euler's totient function, just use
`if (istotient(n + 1, &x), print(x))`.
If n + 1 is a totient, the above prints an `x` such that `φ(x)-1 = n`